# What is the difference between human action recognition and human activity recognition?

Tags: computer-vision, gesture-recognition, surveillance

I would like to know what is the difference between human action recognition and human activity recognition? Are these terms used interchangeably ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A popular review by [Aggarwal and Ryoo](http://cvrc.ece.utexas.edu/mryoo/papers/review_ryoo_hdr.pdf) uses a taxonomy where an action is defined as a single person activity but in general, the terms are used interchangeably.